# two lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, zip

I have two lists created in python like so:

```
list1 = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
list2 = [-4, 8, -4, 8, -1, 2]
```

Now I zipped these two lists into a dictionary like so:

```
d = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

which gives me:

```
{2: -4, 3: -4, 4: -1, 5: 2}
```

What I want to get is a result like this:

```
{2: -4, 3: 4, 4: 7, 5: 2}
```

list1 is becoming the the keys to the new dictionary. If I have two values in list1 that are the same, I want it to add the two values. For example, in list2, 8 and -4 both have the same key 3. Is there a way to add these two values together so the key looks like

```
{3: 4}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
>>> list1 = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
>>> list2 = [-4, 8, -4, 8, -1, 2]

>>> d = {}
>>> for k, v in zip(list1, list2):
        d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + v

>>> d
{2: -4, 3: 4, 4: 7, 5: 2}
```

Comment: +1 I prefer defaultdict as it expresses the intent, but you make a good point about it being easier for beginners to understand `get`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I didn't even think to use get. Another question, I know that dictionaries are unordered, but is it possible to display a dictionary from highest key to lowest key?

Comment: @user1067296 The easiest way to see ordered results is ``print sorted(d.items(), reverse=True)``.

Answer (score 7):

Try using a [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in zip(list1, list2):
    d[k] += v
```

Result:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {2: -4, 3: 4, 4: 7, 5: 2})
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/tJ02h)

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think beginners need to be exposed to *dict.get()* before being introduced to *collections.defaultdict*.  The former builds a solid foundation with core datatypes.  The latter requires knowledge of factory functions, knowing the *int()* with no arguments returns zero, and that the resulting defaultdict displays differently than a regular dict.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember when you are sorting, you incur a big cost (O(nlogn)). Also very likely there is an O(n) temporary space (memory) use. dict are designed to do one job best -- and that is fast lookup/add/delete -- not walk all items in a sorted order (walking in unsorted order is still fine). For small number of items, this is not an issue. It's good to identify the right datas-tructure by knowing its strengths and limitations. There are other datastructures like trees which can provide ordered walk without the big cost (they can do it in O(n)).

Answer (score 0):

You could try dictionary comprehension to combine two lists into a dictionary .

```
list1 = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
list2 = [-4, 8, -4, 8, -1, 2]

{k:v for k,v in zip(list1,list2)}
```

Output:

```
{2: -4, 3: -4, 4: -1, 5: 2}
```